# Put internal search results first in Google Workspace search

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

When using search in the Google Workspace admin console, the user or group I search for is found very quickly.

At first, the relevant results are at the top. But then Google's own help docs end up at the top instead.

Is there a way to prioritize groups of search results (e.g. our user and groups first, help docs next)?

I think this has been the behavior for a while, but it's becoming a major annoyance. Often times I see what I want very quickly, arrow-key down, hit enter and end up offsite, and just because the results updated right when I was navigating down.

[image]